# Condense dataset pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I wish to condense my dataset. Essentially it is a groupby.

### Data

```
id  box     status
aa  box11   hey
aa  box11   hey
aa  box11   hey
aa  box11   hey
aa  box5    hello
aa  box5    hello
aa  box5    hello
aa  box5    hello
aa  box5    hello
bb  box8    no
bb  box8    no
```

### Desired

```
id  box     status
aa  box11   hey
aa  box5    hello
bb  box8    no
```

### Doing

```
df1 = df.groupby(["id"])["box"]).agg()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

If you want to be careful and exclude "id" you can use the subset keyword:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['box', 'status'])
```

EDIT:
To clarify, drop_duplicates() will only drop rows if the full row is duplicated.  Subset just tells it which rows to consider. If you had a row where box='box8' and status='hey', this row would not drop.  Both are duplicates individually but are in a unique combination.

Comment: Ok I can keep the id column by including in subset then? Thanks will try

Comment: drop_duplicates() will drop only drop a row if every element is represented elsewhere in the same combination, but subset determines which rows are considered when looking for full duplicates.  In your current example the only way for drop_duplicates to remove duplicate 'id's would be to call drop_duplicates(subset['id']), because even where id is duplicated, the other columns in the row are a unique pairing.